# Migrating Jira to EC2 and change DB from mysql to postgres

Tags: database, amazon-ec2, jira

Hi we are trying to migrate Jira server (current 6.4) and upgrade at same time over to a new EC2 instance.  I've already done a fresh install of Jira 7.5 on on centOS7 distro and configured it with Postgresql and gone through the setup wizard and setup admin stuff so Jira is completely up and running and usable.  However the old Jira server is running on MySQL and this was lost in communication somehow.  Is it possible to do this or do we have to install MySQL on the new server for this to work.  Following this guide at the moment.  Thanks guys.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/migrating-jira-applications-to-another-server-861253107.html

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the mentioned guide and everything will be OK. Migration via XML backup/restore is database independent.